# kibana installation error while executing from browser

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

i am trying to install kibana . after installing kibana through ubuntu i tried the following commands.

```
 sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload
 sudo  /bin/systemctl enable kibana.service
 sudo  /bin/systemctl  start kibana.service
 curl  127.0.0.1:5601
```

however my programme is executing well in shell but when i am trying to load from browser as 127.0.0.1:5601 it was throwing me error like "problem loading page". i have changed my config file server.host to "0.0.0.0" instead of "localhost". but still throwing me error. how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please share your `kibana.yml`. In your `kibana.yml`, you should have the following:

```
elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200"
```

Also, make sure your `elasticsearch` is indeed running else `kibana` won't be able to connect to it. The easiest way to know if `elasticsearch` is running or not is to do:

```
curl http://localhost:9200
```